Spring RestTemplate - How to remove `client_secret` from the logs?
My backend application currently leaks client_secret inside my log file. I would like to keep the log level of DEBUG except for the RestTemplate where I don't want this line to be executed.
The log line in question looks something like this:
o.s.web.client.RestTemplate : Writing [{client_id=[id-client], client_secret=[xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx], grant_type=[client_credentials], audience=[roles-api]}] as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
And this is how my logback-spring.xml looks like at the moment:
...
    <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="DEBUG"/>
    <Logger name="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate" level="INFO"/>
...

I think the DEBUG level set for org.springframework.web "overrides" the INFO level set for RestTemplate.

Here is what I have done to solve this issue. I've created a custom layout which processes log messages before they are written to the log files. Here is the code:
MaskingPatternLayout.java
package my.project.path;

import ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent;

public class MaskingPatternLayout extends PatternLayout {

    @Override
    public String doLayout(ILoggingEvent event) {
        String message = super.doLayout(event);
        return message.replaceAll("client_secret=\\S*", "client_secret=[****],");
    }
}

And in the logback-spring.xml I've added the following lines:
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
            <layout class="my.project.path.MaskingPatternLayout">
                <pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
            </layout>
        </encoder>
        <file>${LOG_FILE}</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            ...
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

With these changes, my log files now contain masked client secrets and look like this:
o.s.web.client.RestTemplate : Writing [{client_id=[id-client], client_secret=[****], grant_type=[client_credentials], audience=[roles-api]}] as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".
Finally, keep in mind that this is just a fix, and ideally, you should avoid logging sensitive information.

You are able to override toString method and return desired fields.
Hope help.
